# Mongodb displays text instead of HTML

Tags: python, html, mongodb

I scrape a table from a website writtin in Python using Pandas, convert it to HTML (df.to_html()) then insert it into Mongodb.
It stores in Mongodb like this ==> {'fact_html_table':'...'}
[In the Mongodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JrZ8.png)

Then when I use Flask and pymongo to retrieve the data and display it in my website, it displays text instead of table.

Is there any function convert text(from Mongodb) to HTML.
Or a way to insert HTML tags into Mongodb where I can use it as HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning HTML from Flask should be no problem:

You can do like this:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
  return '<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>'
```

However, it can be that you're using Jinja which makes it a bit different, you need to use the `safe` keyword.

Example mytemplate.html

```
{{mysuperduperHTML|safe}}
```

More infos [there](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping)

Comment: Thank you so very much @Laurent Meyer
I forgot to mention that I used Jinja, luckily you expert knew it.
And it works.
Cheers